# Tagging mp3 files

Tags: macos, mp3, tags

I'm looking for a easy to use mp3 tagging program for osx, does anyone have a suggestion?

Note: cmd line programs are ok, but I'd rather have something with a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Commercial id3 taggers:**

- [Jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/) which has many features, but it was slow (at least for me) and it didn't really feel like a Mac OS X app, more like some Java GUI:

[image: Jaikoz]

- [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/) - There's been a lot of talking about this one recently. It seems to provide some kind of tagging *magic*. Never used it myself though.

[image: tuneup]

**Open Source:**

- [Tagger](http://bilalh.github.com/projects/tagger/gallery.html) - Which I really like and use (if I don't want to open the terminal)

[image: tagger]

- [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) which is really popular. Tried it, but didn't like it. Maybe you've got better luck with it.

[image: picard]