# Tagging - copying name files to tags

Tags: mp3

I have started  digitizing my vinyl collection to MP3 and have to type in the name of each track. Is it at all possible to automatically copy the name of the file to the "TITLE" section of the tag editor without having to retype the whole title again in the tags area? I'm doubling up on typing in every song, and it takes an age to do... nevermind sore fingers!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While product recommendations are generally considered out of scope on this site, if you're running Windows (or a Wine-supporting platform such as OS X or Linux) and not already using [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html), I recommend you give it a try -- it's free as in beer and natively supports operations such as "copy each file's name to a given field in its ID3 tag information", including inline transformations such as title-casing and removing extraneous punctuation. I've had excellent results with it, and perhaps you will too!

Comment: Copy & Paste are not doing it for you? Might also help to mention what system you are working with.

Comment: Please tell us what operating system you use, what tag editor, etc. Yes it is possible and you can also easily do it after creating your tracks but we can't help you unless you tell us what you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a quality MP3 Tag editor, as *many* of them have the ability to populate the tags based on file name.

You didn't mention which tagger you're currently trying, nor your OS, so here's a couple of (now-closed) SU questions regarding MP3 taggers you can try:

- Windows: [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](https://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags?rq=1)
- OSX: [Tagging mp3 files](https://superuser.com/questions/409105/tagging-mp3-files)
- Linux: https://superuser.com/questions/3750/mp3-id3-tags-organizer-cleaner-for-linux